# Luaotfload: no writeable cache path error

Tags: luatex

I run `LuaLaTeX` in vscode with this trivial MVE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
Hello World 2244
\end{document}
```

and get the error

> luaotfload-init.lua:301: system : no writeable cache path, quiting".

It runs ok with XeLaTeX.

I have installed with [ansible-texlive](https://codeberg.org/ansible/texlive/src/branch/main/defaults/main.yml) and seen that it attempts to have no local `texmf` dir. Now I fear that my problem is caused by the `texmfcnf.lua` file. I have

```
return { 
  content = {
    variables = {
      TEXMFHOME = "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local",
      TEXMFVAR = "selfautoparent:/texmf-var",
      TEXMFCONFIG = "selfautoparent:/texmf-config",
    },
  },
}
```

which seem to correspond to `texmf.cnf`

```
TEXMFHOME = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFVAR = $SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = $SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-config
```

Are these correct? If not, what should they contain? If yes, what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was indeed in the two config files. They should not contain anything - except for intentional differences to a standard installation.

Thus I removed the all content in `texmf.cnf` and reduced `texmfcnf.lua` to

```
return { 
  content = {
    variables = {  
    },
  },
}
```

Then I ran `luaotfload-tool --update` which built the font name database (in a writable cache!) and checked

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFCACHE
```

which points to a writable directory under my home dir:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var:/home/frank/.texlive2023/texmf-var
```

Comment: Might or might pertain to your situation: It is possible to define the various TeX environment variables in your login shell (maybe `.bashrc`), like this: `export TEXMF=/path/to/wherever` and so forth. I assume you are using Linux, given the paths you wrote above.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will try it out next time..